# Enable character dash if a UI button is pressed

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm currently trying to make a mobile game where my character can dash. All my character movements are manipulated through UI buttons. I have my "Move Left" button and my "Move Right button" with the directional functions. Here's my problem, how can I make a dash movement similar to that of Hollow Knight dash. I want my character to dash if I press a "dash" UI button. Here is my character movement code:

```
Rigidbody2D rb;
float playerspeed;
float movespeed;
float movespeedX;

private void Start()
{
   rb = GetComponent <Rigidbody2D> ();
}
private void FixedUpdate()
{
   Moveplayer(movespeed);
}

public void Moveplayer(float playerspeed)
{
    myrb.velocity = new Vector2( movespeed, myrb.velocity.y);
    if (playerspeed < 0 ||  playerspeed > 0 )
    {
        myanim.SetInteger ("State", 2);
    }
}
public void Left()
{      
    movespeed = -movespeedX;
}
public void right()
{   
    movespeed = movespeedX;
}
public void StopMoving()
{
    movespeed = 0;
}
public void Dash()
{
   //execute dash when UI button is pressed
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Tweak your `movespeed` or `movespeedX` values when the button is activated, reset to default when no longer activated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create movement regardless of other forces, here is an example.

```
private bool enableMovement   = false; 
private float dashingTime     = 1f;
private float dashingStrength = 2f;

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (enableMovement)
       Moveplayer(movespeed);
}
public Dash()
{
    enableMovement = false;
    StartCoroutine(Dashing());
}
private IEnumerator Dashing()
{
    myrb.velocity = new Vector2(movespeed * dashingStrength, myrb.velocity.y);

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(dashingTime);
    enableMovement = true;
}
```

This is an easy simple way to achieve it.